# Extract letters from a string and convert to upper case?

Tags: c++

Here is a program in C++ for a string that accepts all characters but only outputs the letters; if letters are lower case then we should make them upper case.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

using std :: cin;
using std :: cout;
using std :: endl;
using std::setw ;

const int MAX_STR_LEN=100;

int main()
{
    char str1 [MAX_STR_LEN];
    int i;

    cin >> setw(MAX_STR_LEN) >> str1;

    for (int i=0; i <MAX_STR_LEN; i++) 
    {
        if (isalpha(str1[i])) {
            if (str1[i]>='A'&& str1[i]<= 'Z')
                cout << str1[i]; 
            if (str1[i]>='a'&& str1[i]<= 'z')
            {
                str1[i]= toupper(str1 [i]);
                cout << str1[i]; 
            }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This tends to work fine but gives extra letters, seems like I'm 
overlooking something. Also, when I only input numbers it gives
letters such as `PHUYXPU`, something that I didn't input.

Comment: What if the actual input was less than `MAX_STR_LEN`? You forgot to check for the terminating `'\0'` character.

Comment: why not use `std::string`?

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but `isalpha` and `toupper` don't take `char`s. They take `int`s that hold the values of `unsigned char` (or `EOF`, but that's not possible here). Call `isalpha((unsigned char) str1[i])` instead. Plenty of systems make `isalpha(str1[i])` do the same thing, but on some, if `str1[i] < 0`, `isalpha(str1[i])` can misbehave quite badly, for example by crashing your whole program.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i <MAX_STR_LEN; i++)
```

This would mean that you would iterate all the 100 cells of the array irrespective of the length of the string. You should either initialise the array before the cin statement like:

```
for(i=0;i<MAX_STR_LEN;i++)
str1[i] = '\0';
```

or replace the condition in the for loop to iterate only through the length of the array like:

```
for(int i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++) { 
//blah blah blah
```

Comment: Don't call `strlen(str1)` in a loop though. There's no point in computing the length again for every character, it's not going to change.

Comment: Much better condition is `str[i] != '\0'`, or shorter `str[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you can do a lot without a raw loops, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct to_upper {
    char operator()(char c) { return toupper((unsigned char)c); }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string letters, input;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    getline(cin, input);

    copy_if(begin(input), end(input), back_inserter(letters), ::isalpha);
    transform(begin(letters), end(letters), begin(letters), to_upper());

    cout << letters << endl;
}
```

Result:

Enter your name: m1ar7ko0
 MARKO

Comment: One problem in the OP's code is missing is a cast to `unsigned char` before calling `isalpha`. This is also a problem in your version, except made worse because there's no longer a simple way to add that cast.

Comment: You are right, thanks. He can use functor or lambda.

Answer (score -1):

If i got it right you don't need the isalpha() function, you are already removing the numeric and symbols with the subsequent if (str1[i]>='A'&& str1[i]<= 'Z') and if (str1[i]>='a'&& str1[i]<= 'z').

Comment: i tried that, it didnt work. it gave extra letters, and when i only input numbers it gave me letters. my point was to try to be specific as possible to diminish any possibility of invalid output